# How to make listview and GridLayout scrollable

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, scrollable

This is my layout file.My gridlayout is fixed only my listview is scrollable.I have tried to set gridlayout as listview header but then there are two gridlayouts.please tell what am I doing wrong.I want whole layout scrollable including listview below it.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
  android:gravity="center_vertical"  >



  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

 <GridLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnCount="8"
    android:rowCount="7"     
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/terminaterf"
        android:layout_width="80dip"
        android:layout_height="70dip"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:background="#FF4981"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textSize="13sp" />
     </GridLayout      >

     <include 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      layout="@layout/my_listview"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
 </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: add scrollview as your root container bear in mind nesting scrollview is not a good idea

Comment: You should set that gridlayout as a header view of your listview. I didn't understand why you had 2 gridlayouts when you did so,maybe you have a wrong implementation there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  Adding gridlayout to header of listview resolved my issue
```